# How can I delete the item that selected by context menu on Expandable Listview on Android?

Tags: android, contextmenu, hashmap, expandablelistview

I have this code :

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
  super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

  ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =
      (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
  int type =
      ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

      int group =
      ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);

      int child =
      ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);

      //Only create a context menu for child items

      if (type == 1) {
      //menu.setHeaderTitle("Action");
      menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT, 0, "Edit");
      menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE, 1, "Delete");
      }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info1 = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        int groupPos = 0, childPos = 0;

        int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);

        if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
        childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
        }

        return true;

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case MENU_DELETE:

    return true;
  }

  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

I want to delete the item, how can I fill the code of case MENU_DELETE: ? This is the combine of expandable listview and context menu, I want to delete the child by context menu. Thx for the help and explanation

Comment: Have a look at this link http://steveoliverc.wordpress.com/category/android/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this pretty good stuff [Android Context Menu](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/07/30/android-long-click-context-menu/)

```
@Override
 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
        .getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.remove_item:
       quoteResult.remove(info.position);
       ((StockQuoteAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
      return true;
     }
  return false;
  }
```